# Инициализация статического члена класса по умолчанию

Tags: c++

Есть ли какой либо стандарт, который гарантирует что статический член класса будет инициализированн нулем?

```
class Test
{
private:
    static LPVOID start;
}
```

Можно ли гарантированно ожидать что `start` будет инициализирован нулем?

Comment: Да, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Static_initialization

Answer (score 2):

Статический член класса - это глобальная переменная, которую так или иначе нужно объявлять в коде программы. При объявлении ничто не мешает инициализировать её некоторым значением. В вашем случае:

```
LPVOID Test::start = NULL; //инициализируем нулём
```

Comment: Я хочу создать код в котором это будет происходит автоматически, я нехотел бы чтобы пользователь делал что либо дополнительно.

Comment: @Илья К что значит "пользователь делал что либо дополнительно"? Объявление статических полей класса - это обязательная часть его реализации, наряду с реализацией функций-членов класса. Соответственно, должен быть cpp-файл, в котором вся эта реализация присутствует (статические переменные плюс функции).